# How to change default template of firebase reset password page for new password

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

How to change template language of page of reset password for new password in firebase

Answer (score 2):

1. In to the [Firebase Authentication console](https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/_/authentication/emails) console, go to the <kbd>TEMPLATES</kbd> panel.
2. Click <kbd>Email Types</kbd> > <kbd>Password reset</kbd>.
3. Click <kbd>Template language</kbd> in the bottom left.
4. Select the language of your choice in the popup.

[image: console for changing email template language]

If you're looking to change the page that the user lands on when they click the verification link in the email, see the documentation about [creating a custom email handler](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/custom-email-handler).

Comment: Yes I know that, I said after click to link in email address than there is a page to set new password-  How I can change that page language

Answer (score 1):

Firebase default email action page should now support localization when you trigger password resets from Firebase Console using your selected template language.